# Python sum 2D list column coincident

Tags: python, matrix, sum, zip

I'm looking for the most efficient method to do the following calculation:

I have three matrix, like this:

```
[[Brand1, operationCost], [Brand2, operationCost],...]

[[Brand1, maintenanceCost],[Brand2, maintenanceCost]...]

[[Brand1, replacementCost],[Brand2, replacementCost]...]
```

and I need to calculate the total cost, operation+maintenance+replacement, of each of the brands. It is posible that same of the marks are not in all the matrix. And obtain another matrix like this:

```
[[Brand1, totalCost],[Brand2, totalCost]...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy should solve your problems:

example:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
c.sum(0)
Out[5]: array([2, 4, 6])
```

If you want to keep your brands combined with the variables I would use pandas:

example:

```
import pandas as pd
In[9]: df = pd.DataFrame({'brand1': [1, 2, 3], 'brand2': [1, 2, 3]})
In[10]: df
Out[10]: 
    brand1  brand2
0       1       1
1       2       2
2       3       3

In[11]: df.sum()
Out[11]: 
brand1    6
brand2    6
```

Comment: One of the problems i have is that I can´t import numpy or pandas library in my project.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't seem to use python dictionaries, this should work:

```
operation = [[Brand1, operationCost], [Brand2, operationCost],...]
maintenance = [[Brand1, maintenanceCost], [Brand2, maintenanceCost],...]
replacement = [[Brand1, replacementCost], [Brand2, replacementCost],...]

total = [ [ope[0], ope[1]+mai[1]+rep[1]] for ope,mai,rep in zip(operation,maintenance,replacement) ]
```

**Edit:**

Nevertheless you can't use this code above if the lenght of lists or the order of brand change. So the best solution is to use dictionaries:

```
# Your matrix as dictionaries
operation = {Brand1: operationCost, Brand2: operationCost, ...}
maintenance = {Brand1: maintenanceCost, Brand2: maintenanceCost, ...}
replacement = {Brand1: replacementCost, Brand2: replacementCost, ...}
# Get all brands in a container
all_brands = set(operation.keys()+maintenance.keys()+replacement.keys())
# Return 0 as default value if a brand is not in the dictionary
f = lambda x, dic: dic[x] if x in dic else 0
# Compute the total cost of each brand
total = {brand: f(brand,operation)+f(brand,maintenance)+f(brand,replacement) for brand in all_brands}
```

Or for python before the 2.7 version:

```
total = dict([(brand, f(brand,operation)+f(brand,maintenance)+f(brand,replacement)) for brand in all_brands])
```

Comment: It Is going to work even if the length of all the lists is not the same?

Comment: If the lenght of matrix and/or the order of brands change, it won't work. That's why I suggest you use dictionnaries rather than those lists. I'm editing my answer to show you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cromod

Comment: There is a problem in the total line code. If the brand doesn't exist in the dictionary, it gives you an error, and doesn't make the sum.

Comment: Sorry this was stupid... I forgot a function to define 0 as default value. I edited my post.

Comment: I sorted it out with an if...else, but this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pure Python (it does not rely on third party dependencies) and should work even if the length of the lists is not the same:

```
oc = [['Brand1', <operationCost>], 
      ['Brand2', <operationCost>],
      ...,
      ]
mc = [['Brand1', <maintenanceCost>], 
      ['Brand2', <maintenanceCost>],
      ...,
      ]
rc = [['Brand1', <replacementCost>], 
      ['Brand2', <replacementCost>],
      ...,
      ]
total = {}
for lst in [oc, mc, rc]:
    for brand, cost in lst:
        total[brand] = total.get(brand, 0) + cost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tonechas